# Where should I store repetitive data in Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm creating this little Access DB, for the HR department to store all data related to all the training sessions that the company organizes for all the employees.

So, I have a Training Session table with information like date, subject, place, observations, trainer, etc, and the unique ID number.
Then there's the Personnel table, with employer ID (which is also the unique table number), names and working department.

So, after that I need another table that keeps a record of all the attendants of each training session. And here's the question, should I use a table for that in the first place? Does it have to be one table for each training session to store the attendants?

I've used excel for quite some time now, but I'm very new to Access and databases (even small ones like this). Any information will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be one table for persons, one table for trainings, and one for participation/attendance, to minimize (or best: avoid) repetition. Your tables should use primary and foreign keys, so that there are one-to-many relationships between trainings and attendances as well as people and attendances (the attendances table would then have a column referring to the person who attended, and another column referring to the training session).

Google "database normalization" for more detail and variations of that principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: That Wikipedia site cleared thinks a lot. Thank you very much